# Does the chainlink node need access to the keystore.json?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum

Does the chainlink node need access to the keystore.json?

Is it OK if I removed it from the VM?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It pulls the keystore from the db. If you remove the file, it will just be recreated.

Answer (score 4):

Sure, the node you run have its own EOA which store link and pay for gas fee when you perform reverse transaction.